# Verilog Testbench constant exp and pram compilation and simulation errors

Tags: verilog, simulation, hdl, modelsim

Source Code:

```
module SingleOneBit(N,T);

parameter integer w; //width or number of inputs N

input wire [w-1:0] N;
output wire T;   

wire[w*(w-1):0] N1; //for anding all possible combinations of 2 bits 
wire R; // for oring all tha ands. If R = 1 then N contians more than one bit with value 1
wire RS; //ors all the bits of the input. Used for checking if there is one bit with value 1 or all 0s
wire R1; // not of R;


buf(R, 0); //initialy R should be 0;
buf(RS, 0); //initialy RS should be 0;

genvar i, j;

generate

for(i = 0; i<w; i=i+1) begin

or(RS,N[i],RS);

for(j = i+1; j<w; j=j+1) begin

and(N1[(i*w)+j], N[i], N[j]);
or(R,N1[(i*w)+j],R);

end    
end

endgenerate

not(R1, R);
and(T,RS,R1);  

endmodule
```

Testbench Code:

```
`include "C:/Users/Muaz Aljarhi/Google Drive/Muaz/Hardware_Designs/Verilog Course/SingleOneBit.v"

module SingleOneBit_tb();

integer n = 5;

reg[n-1:0] N;
wire T;

SingleOneBit sob(.N(N),.T(T));
defparam sob.w = n;

initial begin

$monitor("N = %b, T = %b",N,T);  



end  

endmodule
```

Compilation of this Verilog Testbench code yeilds the following errors:

> ** Error: C:/Users/Muaz Aljarhi/Google Drive/Muaz/Hardware_Designs/Verilog Course/SingleOneBit_tb.v(7): Range
>   must be bounded by constant expressions.
>   ** Error: C:/Users/Muaz Aljarhi/Google Drive/Muaz/Hardware_Designs/Verilog Course/SingleOneBit_tb.v(11):
>   Right-hand side of defparam must be constant.

How to declare a variable or a constant experssion which can be changed within a test bench? I tried using parameter but parameters are not variables which can be changed. Thanks in advance

Edit: Do I have to declare different instantiations of the module with possibly different input reg variables or there is another way?

I also tried this:

```
SingleOneBit sob(.N(N[0]),.T(T));
defparam sob.w = 32'd5;
```

but simulating, using modelsim yeilds the following:

```
# ** Error: (vopt-2293) The parameter 'w' in the instance ('/SingleOneBit_tb/sob') of ('SingleOneBit') is declared without a value,
# 
# and the instantiation does not provide a value for this parameter.
```

How to avoid getting this error at simulation? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As parameters are compile-time (technically elaboration-time) constants, you cannot have them change during the course of execution. Thus, the first error in which `sob.w` was set to `n` is not valid as `n` cannot be determined to be a fixed value during the elaboration phase (part of compiling the entire design, before simulation can take place).

The second error is a result of the declaration of `SingleOneBit` module `sob` not defining hte `w` parameter. While you define it later with a `defparam`, you need to provide some default value of `w`. You can do this in the module itself by changing the declaration of `w` to include a default value:

```
parameter integer w = 32'd5;
```

As you seem to want to test various widths of this module, I dont see a way around not declaring multiple widths of this module. Of course, you can use a generate statement to produce these module of various width compactly; but I very sure there isnt any way of changing the parameter in the middle of simulation.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that the `defparam` construct might be removed from the language (IEE1800-2009 and IEEE1800-2012 both list it as something that might be  eliminated in the future), so you should avoid using it to allow your code to be compatible with future tools.

Comment: "integer n = 5;" is compile time variable. As I suspect, the reason it can't be used as parameter initializer is to simplify work for compiler.

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov Yup, also, if the compiler did accept that `n` as a 5, if you change `n` in the middle of simulation, it would not be able to change the bit widths of the internal variables (ie, allow the parameter to change with `n`), so it would end up being quite confusing :)

Comment: One can change those during simulation? Didn't knew it. Then probably "genvar" is good replacement.

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov You can certainly change integers during simulation but not parameters

Answer (score 1):

Compiler need some value for parameter at the point of module instantiation.
Provide default parameter value in "SingleOneBit" like this:

```
parameter integer w= 12345;
```

later you can change it with "defparam".

Or you can set parameter in instantiating expression like this:

```
SingleOneBit #(12345) sob(.N(N[0]),.T(T));
```